# Issues with webpack when minify incremental-dom inside vendors bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to use incremental-dom in a project that is processed with webpack and babel
I am separating scripts from vendors automatically with webpack but i'm having a problem with an incremental-dom function the browser console log shows me: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name**

```
function (e) {return 11 === e.nodeType || 9 === e.nodeType} (t)? t.activeElement: null} (e); return n && e.contains (n)? function (e, t) {para (var n = [], r = e; r! == t;) {var o = r; n.push (o), r = o.parentNode} return n} (n, t): []}
```

I can see that the problem is when the Webpack minify  the vendor.bundle.js file because when i set the option minimize as false the code run perfectically.

how can i force the correct minification?

here my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');  
module.exports = (env = {}, argv = {}) => {  
const isProd = argv.mode === 'production';  
return {  
    entry: {  
        brick: './src/brick.js'  
    },  
    output: {  
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'  
    },  
    optimization: {  
        minimize: true,  
        splitChunks: {  
            cacheGroups: {  
                commons: {  
                        test: /node_modules/,  
                        name: "vendor",  
                        chunks: "initial"
                    }
                }
            }
       },
    resolve: {
       modules: [
           path.resolve('./'),
           path.resolve('./node_modules')  
           ]
       },  
  module: {  
            rules:  [  
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'], 
                            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                            }
                        }
                },
                {
                    test: /-tpl\.hbs$/,
                    use: ['babel-loader', 'incremental-bars-loader']  
                }  
            ]  
        },  
  stats: { 
       colors: true  
  },  
  devtool: 'source-map',  
  devServer: {  
          // Display only errors to reduce the amount of output.  
          stats: "errors-only",  
          compress: true,  
          contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),  
          host: 'localhost', //process.env.HOST, // Defaults to `localhost`  
          port: process.env.PORT, // Defaults to 8080  
          open: 'http://localhost:8080/index.html', // Open the page in browser  
      },  
  }  
};
```

package.json :

```
   {  
  "name": "brick",  
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "description": "Base strtucture of webcomponents",  
  "main": "index.js",  
  "author": "Alex Mora <oa.mora>",  
  "license": "MIT",  
  "scripts": {  
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --debug --devtool source-map --output-pathinfo --mode development --progress --colors"  
  },  
  "devDependencies": {  
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",  
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",  
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",  
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",  
  "incremental-bars-loader": "^0.1.0",  
  "webpack": "^4.39.2",  
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",  
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"  
  },  
  "dependencies": {  
    "incremental-dom": "^0.6.0"  
  }  
}
```

brick.js :

```
import {patch, elementVoid, elementOpen, text, elementClose} from 'incremental-dom';  
import template from './brick-tpl.hbs';  

class Brick extends HTMLElement {  
    _root = {};  

  constructor() {  
        super();  
 let root = this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});  
  patch(root, () => {  
            this.render({someCondition: true, text: 'texto'})  
        });  
 let i = 0;  
  setInterval(() => {  
            patch(root, () => {  
                this.render({someCondition: (i % 2) === 0, text: 'texto', numero: i++})  
            });  
  }, 1000)  
    }  

    render(data) {  
        template(data);  
  }  
}  

customElements.define('magic-brick', Brick);
```

brick-tpl.hbs :

```
<div>  
  some text
</div>  
<h1>Hello! {{text}} {{numero}}</h1>  
{{#if someCondition}}  
    <p>  
  es par  
    </p>  
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is minification, Webpack uses Terser by default but seems to have a bug

One possible solution is to change the minimizer plugin,
i change the terser addon to babel-minify-webpack-plugin,
so the optimization section looks like this now

```
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');
optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [new MinifyPlugin()],
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    commons: {
                        test: /node_modules/,
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "initial"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```